# how to set hyperlink in content using pdfbox

Tags: java, servlets, pdfbox

In Below code i want to add hyperlink in "Google.com"

```
contentStream.beginText();
contentStream.setNonStrokingColor(0,0,0);
contentStream.setFont(PDType1Font.TIMES_ROMAN, 8);
contentStream.newLineAtOffset(315, 220);
contentStream.showText("Website: google.com");
contentStream.endText();
```

I want to display hyperlink in google.com and it should redirect when clicking on google.com

Comment: You need to add a link annotation there, too. Alternatively show a full url, some viewers search for URLs in the text and treat them like links.

Comment: Please link at the AddAnnotations.java example in the source code download

Comment: oops, I mean to write "look" at the AddAnnotations.java example.

Comment: PDAnnotationLink txtLink = new PDAnnotationLink();
PDBorderStyleDictionary underline = new PDBorderStyleDictionary();
underline.setStyle(PDBorderStyleDictionary.STYLE_UNDERLINE);
txtLink.setBorderStyle(underline);
PDRectangle position = new PDRectangle();
position.setLowerLeftX(325);
position.setLowerLeftY(210);
position.setUpperRightX(350);
position.setUpperRightY(220);
txtLink.setRectangle(position);
PDActionURI action = new PDActionURI();
action.setURI("http://www.Google.com");
txtLink.setAction(action);
page.getAnnotations().add(txtLink);

Comment: Add Code below and work it IF not link get properly then set PDRectanlge alignment

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this code also worked,

```
contentStream.beginText();
contentStream.setNonStrokingColor(0,0,0);
contentStream.setFont(PDType1Font.TIMES_ROMAN, 8);
contentStream.newLineAtOffset(50,220);
contentStream.showText("Website: google.com");
contentStream.endText();

// create a link annotation
PDAnnotationLink txtLink = new PDAnnotationLink();

// add an underline
PDBorderStyleDictionary underline = new PDBorderStyleDictionary();
underline.setStyle(PDBorderStyleDictionary.STYLE_UNDERLINE);
txtLink.setBorderStyle(underline);

PDRectangle position = new PDRectangle();
position.setLowerLeftX(75);
position.setLowerLeftY(210);
position.setUpperRightX(85);
position.setUpperRightY(220);
txtLink.setRectangle(position);

PDActionURI action = new PDActionURI();
action.setURI("http://www.Google.com");
txtLink.setAction(action);

page.getAnnotations().add(txtLink);
```