# Add hyperlink to pdf files using pdfbox

Tags: java, pdf, pdfbox

I need to create a small tool that adds a hyperlink on the first page of a PDF file. I'm using Apache [PDFBox](https://pdfbox.apache.org/) to read the pdf files.

Any ideas how to add a hyperlink on a page using this library?

I  found this question: [how to set hyperlink in content using pdfbox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50146466/how-to-set-hyperlink-in-content-using-pdfbox), but this doesn't work.

I just want to add a hyperlink on the first page of a pdf file.

```
File file = new File(filename);
PDDocument doc = PDDocument.load(file);

PDPage page = doc.getPage(0);
...
```

I have at least 2 problems with the solution that I found on [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21021502/how-to-add-hyperlink-in-pdf-using-pdfbox):

1. The method drawString(String) in the type PDPageContentStream is not applicable for the arguments (PDAnnotationLink)
2. colourBlue is not initialized

I would prefer to add the hyperlink at the bottom of the page with the URL centered. But for the moment any suggestion will help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all, you need to create a `PDAnnotationLink` like this:

```
PDAnnotationLink link = new PDAnnotationLink();
```

The `link` should have an action:

```
PDActionURI actionURI = new PDActionURI();
actionUri.setURI("http://www.Google.com"); 
link.setAction(action);
```

Finally, you need to define a rectangle at the desired position and finally add the `link` to the page's annotations.

```
PDRectangle pdRectangle = new PDRectangle();

pdRectangle.setLowerLeftX(...);
pdRectangle.setLowerLeftY(...);

pdRectangle.setUpperRightX(...);
pdRectangle.setUpperRightY(...);

link.setRectangle(pdRectangle);

page.getAnnotations().add(link);
```

If you want you can also add an underline for the `link` by calling the `setBorderStyle(...)` methid.

Hope this works for you !

If you want to add some text, then you need to create a `PDPageContentStream` like this:

```
PDPageContentStream contentStream = new PDPageContentStream(doc,  page);
contentStream.beginText();
contentStream.newLineAtOffset(..., ...);
contentStream.showText(...);
contentStream.endText();
contentStream.close();
```

The `newLineAtOffset(..., ...)` method is used for positioning the text at the desired location.

P.S. Sorry for the bad indentation but it is pretty hard to write on the mobile. If you need any further help you can even write me a private message in Romanian.

Comment: It works! The problem is that the hyperlink doesn't have a text. I just see a small underline. But the link is functional!  I don't think I can send you a private message from stackoverflow.

Comment: Have a look at the AddAnnotations.java example in the source code download. The text is just a text, it must be added to your page content stream, not to the annotation.

Comment: @NicuVlad I have edited my answer, please mark it as the accepted answer and upvote me if it helped you. Thanx

Comment: @TothLudovicAndreas, Thanks a lot!

Comment: @NicuVlad One more thing, before doing the stuff with the content stream, try doing link.setColor(...).

Comment: @TothLudovicAndreas, I tried but it just colors the underline. Also, the content stream works, it adds a new text but it's a different entity.